# How Do I Generate All Possible Combinations of the Variables In A Model In R?

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Assuing I have a table with several variables, `a` - `h`, where `h` is the target/y/predicted variable:

```
a <- rnorm(10,5,1)
b <- rnorm(10,5,1)
c <- rnorm(10,5,1)
d <- rnorm(10,5,1)
e <- rnorm(10,5,1)
f <- rnorm(10,5,1)
g <- rnorm(10,5,1)
h <- rnorm(10,5,1)

df = data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
```

I want to run the [AIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) to determine the best possible model for predicting `h`. To do that, I need to run every single combination of `df[1:7]`. So I'd need the AICs of:

```
lm(fomula= h ~ a+b+c+d+e+f+g)
lm(fomula= h ~ a+b+c+d+e+f)
lm(fomula= h ~ a+b+c+d+e)
```

As well as every other configuration of the variables. Is there any way I can do this please?

To get every possible formulation of the variables I've tried:

```
library(combinat)
combn(colnames(df[,1:7]))
```

However, I only got:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

As the output of the above code which is a far cry from what I ultimately want.

Comment: Take a look at `stepAIC` from MASS package

Comment: Better yet, use the `leaps` package for best subset regression without a stepwise constraint. (or `glmulti` or `bestglm`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `step` function. This should give you the best model:

```
step(lm(h~., df),direction = 'both', trace = 0)

Call:
lm(formula = h ~ b + e + f, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b            e            f  
     4.3494      -0.8705      -0.3266       1.2877
```

This model has the lowest `AIC`. You can change `trace = 1`, to look at the intermediate models that were run

Comment: "Best model" - model with lowest AIC reachable from the full model by optimizing individual steps. Often, but now always the same as the model with lowest AIC among all possible combos of these predictors.

Comment: @GregorThomas in this case, the model given is the one with the lowest AIC among ALL possible combos pf these predictors

Comment: I don't see how you can say that... maybe the space is simple enough without interaction terms, but even then there's probably some seed you could set that would make that not true.

Comment: @GregorThomas with the data, you could run all the combinations and compute their AIC and then select the best. Of course the data is simple enough. You can use a real dataset

Comment: Yes, that's my point. The `leaps` or `bestglm` or `glmulti` packages do just that. But `step` does not do that. Sometimes one step will increase AIC, but open up another step that lowers it even more. `step` or `stepAIC` will miss those models.